# Custom Theme Android

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner, android-theme

In the app that I am making I want to theme some of my display widgets (dialog, actionbar, etc) but keep Theme.Holo as a parent for things I don't want to theme (buttons, spinners, etc)

So in my manifest I changed:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

and then in themes.xml I made my CustomTheme and overrode my actionbar and dialog:

```
<!-- Custom Holo (Dark) Theme -->
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CarCastActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

only now my spinners have gone back to an ugly white instead of the flat transparent look.
Why is it doing this? I can attach pictures if it would help

Answer (score 0):

The default Holo theme, which you are using expects a dark background. So the ui elements will have a white translucent color. Trying using the Holo Light theme to have darker ui elements.

```
android:Theme.Holo.Light
```